# Lubuntu 12.04 cannot login via GUI after a kernel update and return error messages

Tags: 12.04, kernel, lubuntu

After kernel update, Lubuntu 12.04 cannot login via GUI and return these error messages:

```
stopping save kernel messages
stopping system v runlevel compatibility
```

Comment: When do you get those lines? What happens before? What happens afterward?

Comment: These messages are just two Upstart jobs (`dmesg` and `rc`) being stopped. It's perfectly OK to see such message during shutdown. Why do you think they are symptoms of errors?

Comment: can't you boot into older kernel?

Answer (score 2):

My solution: Remove extra kernels.

To remove extra kernels:

1. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 for login (first console)
2. With this command you can see all the kernels: `ls /boot/`
3. Remove a kernel with: `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.0.15-30-generic`

   Replace 3.0.15-30 with kernel number you want remove.